# Get current time without Date

Tags: sql, sybase

How do I get the current time only?

```
select getdate()
```

Gives me:

```
Dec 16 2016  5:41PM
```

I want this result:

```
5:41PM
```

Comment: `Select Convert(Time, GetDate())`?

Comment: yes it worked @Siyual you can post it as an answer

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can convert the `GETDATE()` results to a `TIME` datatype to pull the current time:

```
Select Convert(Time, GetDate())
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do that pretty simply; if I correctly understood your problem.

```
SELECT CAST('INSERT THE TIME HERE' AS TIME(0))
```

Answer (score 2):

And if using Sybase ASE 15+ you can use the current_time() function.

```
select current_time() -- returns 'time' datatype
```

You can also use the normal date/time-related and convert/cast functions against the resulting value as needed (eg, changing output format).

Answer (score 1):

This query returns time with format "hh:mm:ss" :

```
Select Convert(Time(0), GetDate())
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need it in 12-hour format you can use CONVERT:

```
SELECT LTRIM(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), GETDATE(), 100), 7))
```

Otherwise the CAST to TIME is simpler.